# Selecting unique combinations only once

Tags: php, sql, select, unique, message

I got a message system with a table like this

```
ID   AID   FID   MESSAGE
1    1     2     Hi
2    2     1     Hi, how are you?
3    3     1     Hello One, what's up?
4    1     2     I'm fine, how about you?
```

ID is the unique Message-ID, AID the ID of the transmitter and FID the ID of the receiver of the message. Message is the message itself.

I want to select all unique combinations with the highest ID, **but** only once, so the output looks like this:

```
ID   AID   FID   MESSAGE
3    3     1     Hello One, what's up?
4    1     2     I'm fine, how about you?
```

The problem is that I can't select properly as AID=2 and FID=1 is as unique as FID=1 and AID=2, but it's in fact the same conversation.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

EDIT: The ID of the user currently logged in is $_SESSION["said"]

EDIT 2: The message system should look something like this, displaying the last message sent in a conversation (just like on facebook).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmvfr.jpg

Comment: I really think you should have a conversation ID and group by that, but what about something like `GROUP BY IF(AID > FID, CONCAT(AID, '|', FID), CONCAT(FID, '|', AID))`?

Comment: What do you mean by unique combination with highest id?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Added more details, see EDIT

Comment: @JohnChrysostom I don't really know, I'm kind of new to PHP/SQL, where can I find this out? - If you mean MySQL, I'm using it with XAMPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is query:

```
select * from table
where ID in (
    select max(id) as maxid
    from table
    group by LEAST(aid, fid), GREATEST(aid, fid)
)
```

if you want to select last message only from/to  $_SESSION["said"], you can use:

```
$query = "select * from table
where ID in (
    select max(id) as maxid
    from table
    where aid = ".$_SESSION["said"]." or fid = ".$_SESSION["said"]."
    group by LEAST(aid, fid), GREATEST(aid, fid)
)";
```

it will give you list of all latest messages sent to/from this user

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm! I think I really have to learn the "group by" and "join" statements..

Answer (score 1):

Might have to modify it depending on your RDBMS (MySQL vs. Microsoft SQL Server, etc.), but the following code should get you headed in the right direction... You'll probably need to modify the string concatenation to use some sort of cast or something, but, like I said, it's RDBMS-dependent.

Pseudocode:

```
select *
from have
where id in
(
    select max(id) as topid
    from have
    group by case when aid<fid then aid+'|'+fid else fid+'|'+aid end
)
```